# Cross forest LDAP query with one way trust

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba

I have two forests of Active Directories: 
Forest A trusts Forest B (one way trust). 
Clients on forest A cannot talk directory to domain controllers on forest B since there is firewall between.
Domain controllers in forests A and B are able to talk to each other (assume on all possible ports).

I want client in forest A to be able to do cross forest LDAP query on forest B, through forest A Domain Controller. By using crossRef, it looks like client needs direct access to LDAP port to forest B domain controller, is there another way to achieve this? Can I make the call through forest A domain controller instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LDAP query on forest B, through forest A Domain Controller

That just isn't the way it works. Even if there was a two-way trust, any query in Forest B would happen on a Forest B domain controller (or Global Catalog - usually the same as a DC).

So regardless of how you authenticate, you will need a network path open to one of the LDAP ports:

- 389 - default LDAP port
- 636 - LDAP over SSL (LDAPS)
- 3268 - Global Catalog, which returns results for all domains in the forest. Only useful if there is more than one domain in the forest.
- 3269 - GC over SSL

If you don't specify any port, 389 is used. For any of the others, you need to specify a port.

The "trust" just means that you can use credentials from one domain to authenticate to the other domain. So in your case, since Forest A trusts Forest B, then you can use credentials from Forest B to authenticate on a computer joined to Forest A.

Since Forest B does not trust Forest A, you will need to authenticate using an account on Forest B when you perform the search.

Comment: So I understand from your answer, in order to make query on forest B, the client on forest A needs LDAP port access on Forest B domain controller? There is no way to "proxy" the request through forest A domain controller?

Additionally, what is crossref is used for? to direct requests from specific domain to specific domain controllers?

Comment: There is no way to proxy the requests, no. And you're right, `crossRef` is there really just as a directory of known external domains so that a referral can be returned (i.e. "I know where you can find that" instead of "I have no idea what you're talking about"). More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/referrals